# Excatly how to test? (Unittest, JUnit, PhpUnit)

Tags: java, php, unit-testing, testing, junit

Well this question might be too localized.
Lets suppose I have forum system to test. Lets delete an user and his posts. Let me use a pseudo-code for the sake of simplificity:

```
class User
{
    function add() { ... }

    function delete (userID)
    {
        container::getOrCreateUserPostObject.deletePostsByUserID (userID)
        DELETE FROM users WHERE ID = userID
    }
}

class UserPost
{
    function deletePostsByUserID (userID)
    {
        DELETE FROM posts WHERE USERID = userID
    }
}
```

this now must be tested:

```
function testDeleteUser()
{
    container::getOrCreateUserObject.add();
    container::getOrCreateUserObject.add();
    container::getOrCreateUserObject.delete (1)
    // now check in the DB that how many records left, really one was deleted etc.
}
```

another test

```
function testDeletePosts
{
    container::getOrCreateUserPostObject.deletePostsByUserID (1);
    // again, now check in the DB that how many records left, really one was deleted etc.
}
```

this looks OK so far. The user deletion and user posts deletion works, and their test standalone.
Yes, standalone. We checked if its OK to delete an user and checked if its OK to delete his post. We **didnt** check if we delete an user with his posts works! There are two good working "lego" elements but is that OK if we put them together?
If I put this "global" test to `testDeleteUser()` then I repeat the post-deletion test code...

Comment: You've introduced a tight coupling between User and UserPost which will make it essentially impossible to test User in isolation or to give it a mock UserPost to work with.

Comment: The whole point of unit testing is that you test functional units ___in isolation___ so that you're not testing dependencies at the same time, and you do that by mocking any dependencies.

Comment: GordonM, ok thats right, I dont use "static" classes, they are object in reality, they can be replaced and mocked

Comment: then how to test them together, where? If its not "Unit test" then its the "integration test" ?

Comment: Testing that the application works, that deleting a user also deletes all that users posts, would be an integration test... often BDD tools would be used to automate/script that type of testing

Comment: @GordonM, I refactored the code a bit

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i get you right, but in a test, you should not really rely on specific user id's like you are doing in testDeletePosts(), you should rather add a user here as well, add some posts, and delete these posts again. So your test is completely independent.

Update:

Something like this for checking the referential integrity

```
function testDeleteUsersAndPosts
{
    addedUsers[0] = user.add();
    addedPosts[0] = post.add(addedUsers[0], 'first Post')
    addedPosts[1] = post.add(addedUsers[0], 'second Post')

    addedUsers[1] = user.add();
    addedPosts[2] = post.add(addedUsers[1], 'third Post for the second user')

    // Check how many posts you have
    allPosts = post.get().count()

    for (id in addedUsers)
    {
         user.delete(id)
    }


    // Check how many posts you have now
    allPostsNow = post.get().count();

    return allPostsNow == (allPosts -3)
}
```

And something like this for checking the Post deletion only

```
function testDeletePosts
{
    userID = user.add();
    addedPost = post.add(userID, 'first Post')

    // Check how many posts you have
    allPosts = post.get().count()

    post.delete(addedPost)

    return post.get(addedPost) == false
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, could you confirm that with real code?